# Is there an adjective expressing that a certain thing is to be chosen?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, adjectives

I'm translating a literature list, and roughly translated, one of the entries reads "Any book of approximately 250 pages, dealing with the topic chosen for the argumentative essay" – but the word corresponding to "any" has a much stronger sense of 'chosen by the student'. If I were to rephrase it, I'd say "The student should choose any book of approximately 250 pages, dealing with..."

My question, then, is: is there a single adjective that I can use here, in this sense?

I've thought about "An optional book of...", but that seems to imply that the student can choose not to use a book, rather than that they are supposed to use a book, but that they may choose any book. I've also thought about "A choice book of..." but I have a feeling that that means 'well-chosen' rather than 'possible to choose'?

As always, I'd be immensely grateful for any help I can get :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would use "a book **of the student's choice**".

[**Of X's choice**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/of-your-choice) (often *of your choice*, but equally valid as *of my choice*, *of her choice*, *of the President's choice*, etc.) is an idiom that means "that X chooses from all of the available options".  This implies that the student can choose any book, but unlike *optional*, means that the choice itself is mandatory.

Comment: Yes!!! Of course! Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't think of this myself...

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you ask in your question is different from what you ask in the title. The answer to the title might include "**selectable**", but of course this word cannot be used the way you want, because what you want is *not* an adjective for "able to be chosen" but rather for "that is to be chosen". One option (already given by *Stangdon*) is "**any book of your choice**". Another option is simply "**any chosen book**", because in your context (i.e. it appears as one entry in a list) it implies that the one who picks from the list is to choose the book if he/she picks that entry.

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course! I've fixed it now. Thanks! :)